# Spectral clustering implementation in python yields nonsensical results

Tags: python, clustering

I am trying to implement spectral clustering in python. I'm using [these excellent notes as a guide](https://people.csail.mit.edu/dsontag/courses/ml14/notes/Luxburg07_tutorial_spectral_clustering.pdf). As the notes suggest, I'm using a toy model where I generate random numbers that come from `k` Gaussians (i.e. `k` clusters). For my example I set `k=4`, and there are `50` points each from each cluster. I thus expect the clustering to yield `k=4` clusters with an equal number of points. This does not happen, however, and I also observe weird eigenvectors. At this point I'm not sure what I'm screwing up, but below I detail my MRE.

I generate the random data as follows:

```
def generate_random_data(N=200, n_gaussians=4, separation=2, variance=0.05):
    mus = [separation*(i+1) for i in range(n_gaussians)]
    N_per_gaussian = int(N / n_gaussians)

    data = []
    for i in range(n_gaussians):
        for j in range(N_per_gaussian):
            val = np.random.normal(loc=mus[i], scale=np.sqrt(variance))
            data.append(val)
    return data
```

I use the following similarity function:

```
def sim(xi,xj,sigma=1):
    return np.exp(-np.abs(xi-xj)/(2*sigma**2))
```

which I use to form the similarity matrix:

```
def form_sim_matrix(data,sigma=1):
    n = len(data)
    S = np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i,n):
            sval = sim(data[i],data[j],sigma=sigma)
            S[i,j] = sval
            S[j,i] = sval
    return S
```

I create a fully connected similarity graph:

```
def create_similarity_graph(data):
    n = len(data)
    S = form_sim_matrix(data,sigma=1)
    A = np.copy(S)
    for i in range(n):
        A[i,i] = 0
    return A
```

I then put everything together:

```
k = 4
N = 200

data = generate_random_data(n_gaussians=k, N=N, variance=0.05)
```

This results in the following data:

[image]

```
W = create_similarity_graph(data)

# degree matrix
D = np.diag(np.array(np.sum(W,axis=1)))

# Laplacian
L = D - W

eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(L)

# eigenvalues in increasing order
rearranged = sorted(zip(eigenvalues, eigenvectors.T), key=lambda x: x[0].real, reverse=False)
```

The resulting eigenvalues and vectors look like this:

[image]

The smallest eigenvalue is 0, and the corresponding eigenvector is all 1s, as expected. However, the remaining eigenvalues and eigenvectors look weird, and nothing like the example [in the notes](https://people.csail.mit.edu/dsontag/courses/ml14/notes/Luxburg07_tutorial_spectral_clustering.pdf) (Fig. 1, bottom panel). I'm not sure what to make of all the "noise".

```
# prep data for k-means clustering
U = np.transpose(np.array([rearranged[i][1] for i in range(k)]))

# k-means clustering
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k).fit(U)
labels = kmeans.labels_
```

When I check the histogram of labels, I get:

[image]

I would expect an equal frequency for each label, because that's how the data was generated: equal number of data points from each Gaussian.

What am I doing wrong? You can download the full python script [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uxxlbkhkhanemmf/mre.py?dl=0).

Comment: Spectral clustering is sensitive to the choice of data similarity matrix. In your case, even when the data are fixed, the similarity matrix will change when you change `sigma`. What happens if you use different values of `sigma`?

Comment: @Sycorax well I'm using `sigma=1` becuase that's what the example in the notes use. In any case, trying `sigma=0.1, 2, 5` don't seem to make any discernible difference. There are still 3 labels, and the eigenvectors look similar...

Comment: If you're trying to re-create the results in the reference, note that the reference you're looking at uses the Gaussian kernel function/RBF kernel in section 2.2: $$\exp\left(-\frac{\| x_i - x_i \|^2_2}{2\sigma^2}\right).$$ But your code uses the Laplacian kernel function $$\exp\left(-\frac{| x_i - x_i |}{2\sigma^2}\right).$$ For scalar values $x_k$, the RBF reduces to $$\exp\left(-\frac{( x_i - x_i )^\color{fuchsia}2}{2\sigma^2}\right)=\exp\left(-\frac{| x_i - x_i |^\color{fuchsia}2}{2\sigma^2}\right),$$ which is the expression on page 8. The code is missing an exponent.

Comment: @Sycorax Oh, thanks, I completely missed that. I now get the correct distribution of labels, but the eigenvectors still look the same.

Comment: It's common, when writing code, to make errors like missing an exponent and get bogus results. You're on the right track, comparing your implementation to a publication, but ultimately this is just a debugging exercise. My advice is to go through line by line and make sure you're doing *exactly* what the authors do.